# What’s the difference between these two “she saw”, “she has seen”?

Tags: past-tense, past-simple

I want to ask you what is the difference between these two sentences:

> She has seen the real meaning in these messages
>
> She saw the real meaning in these messages

And to know if both of them are grammatically correct. I know that saw is standalone word and seen is used alongside has, had, have etc. But what’s the difference between these two?

Comment: The first is the present perfect - an event that began in the past but is still relevant now. Maybe it happened recently. The second is the past simple - an event that happened in the past and is now complete.  The difference is subtle when referring to life experiences because everything that a person experiences is still relevant while they continue to live.

Comment: American English often uses the past simple where British English uses the present perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your sentences are grammatically correct.

Now, let's go back to their difference in meaning.

> **She has seen the real meaning in these messages. *( This could mean that She has just seen .... , or she has seen at some indefinite time
>   during the day/week, etc. );***
>
> **She saw the real meaning in these messages. *( - implies a terminated period of time, some earlier period during the day/week/
>   month, etc. )*;**

*Moreover, an example with the phrase "over the course of time" would make the things clear.*

e.g.

> **The difference has constantly been changing *over (the) course of time. ( indefinite frequency - it might have changed by this moment - recently  );***